# How to notify client's browser about some event on server?

Tags: javascript, python, comet, tornado, c10k

I'm using python (Tornado) on server side and some javascript on a client side. I have the common situation - one user send a message to another. And I want server to notify client's browser (reciever of the message) about new message. How can I do it? Should I establish long-alive connection with client (maybe using websocket) or something else?

PS
For establishing conenction via websocket I found good library [TornadIO](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/TornadIO/)

PS2
So, due to high load of project establishing connection betwebb server and each client looks suspicious. I afraid of c10k problem. May be it's only lack of my knowledge.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682198/writing-a-chat-application/3682211#3682211 (and other answers on the same question)

Comment: it's good, but I have a question about comet. I afraid of situation when 10k users have a connection and after this no one can connect (c10k problem)

Comment: If you anticipate having that many users connected I one chat server, you will have lots of other problems to worry about besides your underlying architecture

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using python (Tornado) on server side and some javascript on a client side. I have the common situation - one user send a message to another. And I want server to notify client's browser (reciever of the message) about new message. How can I do it? Should I establish long-alive connection with client (maybe using websocket) or something else?

Using a realtime web server such as Tornado - yes. TornadIO looks like a good solution since it'll use socket.io which has fallback options for older browsers.

The [Wikipedia entry on the C10k issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) provides a list of servers that have resolved this problem:

> A few web servers have been developed to counter the C10K problem:
>
> - nginx, which relies on an event-driven (asynchronous) architecture, instead of threads, to handle requests (WordPress.com uses nginx to solve the C10K problem)[2]
> - Lighttpd, which relies on an asynchronous architecture to handle requests[3]
> - Cherokee, a lightweight web server[4]
> - Tornado, a non-blocking web server and web application framework[5] written in Python
> - Apache Deft, asynchronous, non-blocking web server running on the JVM
> - JBoss Netty, a NIO client server framework which enables quick and easy development of network applications such as protocol servers and clients[6]
> - Node.js, asynchronous, non-blocking web server running on Google's V8 JavaScript engine[7]
> - EventMachine, an asynchronous, non-blocking web server running on Ruby EventMachine
> - Yaws, a web server written in Erlang; profiting from Erlang's extremely lightweight processes.
> - Medusa, a non-blocking web server library written in Python

As you'll see, Tornado is listed.

Beyond this your question is potentially more about [horizontal scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability#Scale_horizontally_.28scale_out.29) than it is about how to achieve server to client notifications.

Depending on which [realtime server solution](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide#self-hosted) you choose this might never become an issues. For example, a single instance of [Caplin System's Liberator](http://www.caplin.com/caplin_liberator.php) can achieve a lot more than 10,000 persistent connections.