# Whole page loads in div after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, autoload

I want to make a chat from scratch and I'm stuck trying to load div using ajax, but when I do that, my whole page shows inside that div.

```
<script>
    function auto_load(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "chat.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#chatbox").html(data);
            } 
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        auto_load();
    });
    setInterval(auto_load,2000);
</script>
```

Comment: What does `chat.php` output?

Comment: @showdev the same page where that code is. Maybe i should create another page and put the code that i want to show?

Comment: It depends on how you've constructing things, but I'd suggest calling a PHP script that only returns chat data to be displayed. As you have it now, whatever HTML is returned by `chat.php` will be displayed in the `#chatbox`.

Comment: @showdev ok i've made it work...thank you

Comment: Ok great. If you'd like, post an answer of how you solved it. You also might find [websockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682198/writing-a-chat-application) interesting.

Comment: @showdev Ok thank you. Do you know how to fix when i submit message to not scroll to top, so when i submit message, it sends me to the top of the page.

Comment: And yeah, i created load.php page and changed `url: "chat.php"` to load.php page and put the chat showing code inside of it.

Comment: That might be better as a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). One idea is to submit data with AJAX so as not to reload the page.